# Multivariate Multiple Linear regression using only numpy

Tags: python, optimization, regression, linear-regression

I am looking to build a multivariate, multiple linear regression model with N dependent variables and M independent variables. I was looking around and cannot seem to find an implementation. I did some research and found some notes here: http://users.stat.umn.edu/~helwig/notes/mvlr-Notes.pdf on slide 51. This seems very simple to implement:

```
import numpy as np


M = 10
N = 3
p = 15

Y = np.random.rand(p,N)

X = np.random.rand(p,M)

A = np.dot(np.transpose(X),X)
B = np.dot(np.transpose(X),Y)

sol = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
```

where sol outputs the matrix of coefficients.  I eventually will be scaling this up to extremely large datasets. My main concern is the accuracy in this method. To be quite honest it seems all too simple. Can someone weigh in on whether this is sufficient in a multivariate, multiple regression or is there some package or anything else that I can use that is better?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on behind the scenes than you think. What you are looking at is the least squared solution to a system of an overconstrained linear system of equations. Let me explain it like this. You have `p` equations and `q` unknown.

Case 1: `p < q`  Infinitely many solutions. The matrix `A` of size `p x q` is singular and so infinitely many solution exists. They can be found by finding the particular solution and basis for the null space. `np.linalg.solve` can't be used to solve such a system as it only expects full rank square matrices. You can use `np.linalg.lstsq` instead.

Case 2: `p = q` Unique Solution. This means that the `p x q` matrix is invertible and you can solve the system `Ax = b` using `x = A^(-1) b`. In fact, when you call `np.linalg.solve`, this is exactly what's happening.

Case 3: `p > q` No solution exists. But we can approximate by projecting the vector `b` orthogonally onto the column space of matrix `A`. This means that we want to find a vector `b_hat` such that `b_hat + w = b` where `w` is some arbitrary vector perpendicular to `b_hat` and `b_hat` lies in the column space of the matrix A. Hence, there is some `x_hat` such that `A * x_hat = b` and `A^(T) w = 0` (because `w` lies in the left null space). As `w = b - b_hat`, we have `A^(T) w = A^(T) * b - A^(T) * ( A * x_hat )`. Hence, we come to a solution, `x_hat = (A^(T) * A)^(-1) * A^(T) * b`. This `x_hat` is the best approximate solution to the system of linear equations with `p > q`. It can be proved mathematically but I think this is a plausible explanation. Again, `np.linalg.solve` can't be used to solve this type of linear system but there is another routine `np.linalg.lstsq` that can be used.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response! My data will eventually result in a very large matrix and so I assume np.linalg.solve will no explicitly find the inverse but rather solve using LU decomposition correct? So if p > q it's safe for me to just substitute linalg.solve with linalg.lstsq correct?

Comment: Yes! `np.linalg.lstsq` will probably be faster and more accurate as it directly wraps BLAS least squared routine.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much